# Left semi Join in Hive for multiple table

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

How can we use left semi join in multiple tables . For example, in SQL the query to retrieve no. of employees working in US is :

```
select name,job_id,sal 
from emp 
where dept_id IN (select dept_id 
                  from dept d 
                       INNER JOIN Location L 
                       on d.location_id = L.location_id 
                       where L.city='US'
                  )
```

As IN query is not supported in Hive, how can we write this in Hive.

Comment: Are you still here?

Answer (score 0):

Use `exists` instead:

```
select e.name, e.job_id, e.sal 
from emp e
where exists (select 1
              from dept d join
                   location L 
                   on d.location_id = L.location_id 
              where l.city = 'US' and d.dept_id = e.dept_id
             );
```

You can refer to the [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries), which covers subqueries in the `WHERE` clause.

This query appears to be answering the question:  What employees work in departments that have a location in the US.  You can also do this in the `FROM` clause with a subquery;

```
select e.name, e.job_id, e.sal 
from emp e join
     (select distinct d.dept_id
      from dept d join
           location L 
           on d.location_id = L.location_id 
      where l.city = 'US'
     ) d
     on d.dept_id = e.dept_id;
```

I should note, though, that "US" is not usually considered a city.

EDIT:

Obviously, if a department can only have one location, then "semi-join" is not necessary.  The `SELECT DISTINCT` can just be `SELECT` . . . Or, you can use the `JOIN`s as in Dudu's answer.  In any case, the `EXISTS` will work.  In many databases it would have good (sometimes the best performance); I'm not sure about the performance implications in Hive.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz . . . Yes.  A department could (reasonably) have multiple locations in the same city/country.  Your version will return duplicates.  A semi-join only simply checks for existence in the second table, so it cannot duplicate rows in the first.

Comment: Not with this table structure where `dept` has `location_id`

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz . . . You are assuming that `dept` has only one row per `dept_id`.  Given the original question (which explicitly specifies a semi join), I'm not sure that is necessarily true.  In almost any other context, that assumption would be really reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a simple inner join

```
select  e.name
       ,e.job_id
       ,e.sal 

from                emp         as e

        join        dept        as d

        on          d.dept_id = 
                    e.dept_id

        join        location    as l

        on          l.location_id   =  
                    d.location_id

where   l.city='US'
```

---

P.s.

Hive does support `IN`.

The only issue with your query is that `dept_id` of `emp` is not qualified (should be `emp.dept_id`).
This works:

```
select name,job_id,sal 
from emp 
where emp.dept_id IN (select dept_id 
                  from dept d 
                       INNER JOIN Location L 
                       on d.location_id = L.location_id 
                       where L.city='US'
                  )
```

Comment: Hi, still here?